# aggregate/ merge a list of dataframes by variable names (R)

Tags: r, list, merge, aggregate

I have a list of dataframes which look similiar to this:

```
Date <-  c("Jan-22", "Dec-21", "Nov-21", "Sep-21")
A_B <- c(5,6,7,9)
A_C <- 1:4
B_D <- 4:7
df1 <- data.frame(Date, A_B, A_C, B_D)

Date <-  c("Jan-22", "Dec-21", "Nov-21", "Sep-21")
A_C <- 1:4
B_D <- 13:16
D_F <- c(5,6,7,8)
df2 <- data.frame(Date, A_C, B_D, D_F)

ListofDF <- list(df1, df2)
```

My original List contain some more dataframes and my dataframes more Variables, but all share the Variable Date (as Character). Now I would like to merge/ aggregate all the different dataframes in the list to one.
So it should merge acording the Date column and aggegate (mean) the Variables Values, if those names are the same.

My disired output would be somthing like that

```
Date <-  c("Jan-22", "Dec-21", "Nov-21", "Sep-21")
A_B <- c(5,6,7,9)
A_C <- 1:4
B_D <- c(8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5)
D_F <- c(5,6,7,8)

df3 <- data.frame(Date,A_B, A_C, B_D, D_F)
```

So same dates, but the mean of values, if there are the same variable names.

i hope I could clarify what I need and thanks in andavance.

**Edit**
Finally I found a solution:

```
MyOutput1<- List1 %>% reduce(full_join, by = "Date")

List2 <- melt(MyOutput1, id.vars = "Date")

res <- aggregate(value ~ Date + variable, 
                 transform(List2, variable = sub("\\..*", '', variable)), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Still I think its not a very nice solution, does anyone have any Idea for a better solution?

Comment: You need to tag R language

Comment: Is matching on the variable names important? Or would just matching on the Date column be ok?

Comment: Matching Variable names is important as well. So at the moment I try something (very laborious) like 
MyOutput1<-ListofDf %>% reduce(full_join, by = "Date")


List2 <- melt(MyOutput1, id.vars = "Date")



res <- aggregate(value ~ Date + variable, 
                 transform(List2, variable = sub('\\*.*.', '', variable)), mean, na.rm = TRUE) (the sub in this function is not right yet)

Comment: To be more exactly it need to be the mean of the Monthly values of the same columns

Comment: You mean `Reduce`, not `reduce`

Comment: reduce from purrr package. (just copied it from my skript and works fine there for me)

Comment: Correction : `sub("\\*.*.", "", variable)`, note the double backslash

Comment: @Sulz Have you seen my correction regarding your proposed code ? You seem to come close to the problem

Comment: `res <- aggregate(value ~ Date + variable, transform(List2, variable = sub('\\*.*.', '', variable)), mean, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: `df3 <- dcast(res, Date  ~ variable) %>% select(- A_C.y, - B_D.y) %>% rename(A_C = A_C.x, B_D = B_D.x)`

Comment: Hey Julien, I see your solutions its not completly good yet. My List 2 have cases like A_B.x, A_B.x.x and A_B.x.x.x (and with y the same) so I nee for my (sub/ gsub) somehow to take everything with after the frist . . Not sure about that